# Hover Div issue

Tags: html, css

I am working on a hover effect for blocks within my site.  I finally got everything working until I got to the last block. The hover is displaced as you can see in [this link sample](http://lfwebz.biz/css_placement_issue.html).

Here is the CSS I am using, but I don't see what the issue is, since it works correctely for the first two blocks.

```
#panel-seventh-wrapper .region {
    position: relative;
}

#panel-seventh-wrapper .region .block-block {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 99999;
}

#panel-seventh-wrapper .region .block-block .block-inner {
    width: 288px;
    height: 122px;
    background: orange;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
}

#panel-seventh-wrapper .region:hover .block-block {
    display: block;
}
```

I added clearfix thinking that would help, but no go.

Any help and guidance would be appreciated.  Thank you.

if it helps, the actual issue is here: [enter link description here](http://latrelle.lfwebz.biz/) on portfolio site I started yesterday. Scroll down and hover over the third image under the slider block.

Comment: Please create a fiddle with your code.

Comment: Have you tried this: `#panel-seventh-wrapper .region .block-block:hover`?

Comment: What about using positioning with the last-child pseudo selector?

Comment: Nothing happens when i hover on the given example… am i missing something..?!!

Comment: What did you think adding a clearfix was going to do?

Comment: The included link has no hover that I see either. Create a small use case in jsFiddle.

Comment: Hi TJ, the page is just images I cut out from the actual site.  If you would like to look I have posted the URL above.  Thank you.

Comment: sheriffderek, I was thinking that since the element contained floats, the fix would clear up and issue related to containing everything.

Comment: Hi Daniel, I am using :hover on the region like this:`#panel-seventh-wrapper .region:hover .block-block {
    display: block;`
}  ----I did try the :hover on block-block, nothing happen when I would hover over the blocks.

Comment: If I create a use case in jsFiddle, everything works there, so I am certain there is something conflicting in the actual drupal space tha tI just don't see.  the url to the location is [link](http://latrelle.lfwebz.biz)

Comment: You were just lucky that it was working. Either way - you should create a fiddle. This isn't a free "go look at my website and fix it" service. Take the time to make a case if you want help.

Comment: sheriffderek - that is actually why i did not add the link initially.  since my CSS worked perfectly well while sitting in a blank html file, not surrounded by a ton of drupal code, I had to assume there was something within drupal that I needed to address that I could not find, hence the reason for asking for assistance.

Answer (score 0):

The first two are working because they just happen to be the right size. The third is doing exactly what it's supposed to, but because the size is wrong, it's showing that your code isn't specific. You specify that it should be absolutely positioned, but how. Put a top or left or right or bottom combination.

```
.region .block-block
    position: absolute; /* absolute what? */
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 2; /* 2 is more that 1... you don't need 999 */
}
```

If you feel like learning, here is the code I would use instead:

### HTML

```
<div class="your-box">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/400/300" alt="" />
    <div class="hover-cover">
        <div class="text-w">
            <p>Hello. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
* { /* google it */
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.your-box {
    position: relative;
    /* so you can position things absolutely to it, inside - to its boundary */
    border: 1px solid blue;
    /*just to see*/
    width: 300px;
    /* the box width --- (smaller than image) */
}

.your-box img { /* make box image adhere to size */
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.your-box .hover-cover {
    position: absolute; /* posit ion based on relative parent */
    top: 0; left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: orange;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 1em;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}

.your-box:hover .hover-cover {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity .3s ease-in-out;
}
```

[a jsFiddle:](http://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/6EpVy/)

Comment: Thx so much!! I really appreciate it. Just a little comment, for which I hope I won't get hammered down for: I don't mind learning at all, if u note the css code I originally posted what I created from ready and testing, but after u have stared at something for a couple of days, u just can't see the little stuff.  I had not even noticed the size difference.  I'm sure there are people that just want someone to do their work, but I think most just need help with getting over a specific hole that they didn't even realize they dug for themselves.  Again thank you very much!!!

Comment: It's hard when you are working in a theme or framework and there might be styles you don't necessarily know affecting your changes. Perfect reason to get out of your code into a test area. Really understanding positioning is what most people gloss over - and then they have a hard time trouble-shooting. Good Luck.

Comment: That is definitely an issue here.  this is a new responsive theme that I am learning.  Thought I had most things down pact, but obviously not :).  Thanks again,  Really appreciate it.

Comment: I decided at one point to make everything myself and it took a while, but I'm certainly never in the dark now. Just remember to think of the content(html) the styles(css) and the PHP(the thing that spits out chunks of html) as what they really are and keep them separate in your mind. Everything is so simple when it clicks but such a mess before it does.

Comment: Don't forget to up-vote helpful comments and answers, and to mark answers that are correct, as answered.